Complex representation of electric field
Hi I have been struggling for a while. Let's say I represent my complex field as $E_1=Ae^{i\omega t}$. Let's say this is the input to a component that takes in two inputs and is supposed to split the power in half between the two outputs while giving a 90 degree phase difference between them, as shown below in the transfer matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&i/\sqrt2\\i/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
This transfer matrix get's multiplied by a 2x1 vector which are the inputs to the system, in this case only one input is used, E1.
This results in the following fields at the output
$$E_{out1}=\frac{A}{\sqrt2}e^{i\omega t}$$
$$E_{out2}=i\frac{A}{\sqrt2}e^{i\omega t}$$
By looking at the two outputted complex field I can already tell there is a 90 degree phase shift due to "i", but cannot seem to get a grasp on how I can plot this in the time domain to show the physical 90 degree phase shift.
To do so would I have to do the following:
$$Re(E_{out1})=\frac{A}{\sqrt2}cos(\omega t)$$
$$Re(E_{out2})=-\frac{A}{\sqrt2}sin(\omega t)$$
My assumption in doing this is that these are fields that I would actually measure in a real world scenario due to my assumption in how i represented my original signal where Re(E1)=cos(wt). If anyone could give me any guidance on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/831637/2451

Should I have not posted again? I have tried simplifying my question in this post.

Why do you think $-\sin(\omega t)$ isn't the right answer?

@yoga545 Do you know what is the phase of a sinusoidal wave
? Could you tell me what is the phase of this field: $E = -\sin(\omega t)$?

Note: $A$ is in general complex. You've written the result for when $A$ is real, which is one possible case.

@ThePhoton well as of right now I do think $-sin(\omega t)$ is the right answer when I take the Real part of Eout2

@tToE $-sin(\omega t)$ is $cos(\omega t)$ shifted 90 degrees forward. Is that not right?

One simple way to deal with "i" thing is to use Euler's identity
$$
i = e^{i\pi/2}
$$
so you can write
$$
E_{out2}=\frac{A}{\sqrt2}e^{i(\omega t+ \pi/2)}
$$
I hope it helps
